# Find ${\rm d}y/{\rm d}x$ and simplify as much as possible, $y=x/(2x+5)^3$

Tags: calculus

My answer is $-6x(2x+5)^2+(2x+5)^{-3}$. I am wondering if my answer is right and whether I am able to simplify more?

Comment: "Simplified" is in the eye of the beholder. Another answer would combine your two terms to make a single fraction with denominator a power of $(2x+5)$. You can easily check your answer with a graphing program or calculator. I just did, and your answer is wrong.

Comment: @RoryDaulton With the equation he has (which is wrong), even the beholder sees making it into a single fraction with denominator $(2x+5)^3$  (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+-6x%282x%2B5%29%5E2%2B%282x%2B5%29%5E%28-3%29) as far from being simplified.

Comment: I agree $100\%$ with Rory: "simplified is in the eye of the beholder". In practical life, you should always try to leave your expression in a form that makes it easier to work after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
y = x(2x+5)^{-3} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = x(2(-3)(2x+5)^{-4}) + (2x+5)^{-3} \\
= (2x+5)^{-4}(-6x +2x+5) \\
= \frac{5-4x}{(2x+5)^4}
$$

Comment: Can you explain line 3? Up until then I understand what you did. I understand that you placed (2x+5)^4 in the denominator. However,  I do not understand the third line. What happened to the sum in the numerator?

Comment: write $(2x+5)^{-3}$ as $(2x+5) (2x+5)^{-4}$ so both the main summands have the same denominator

Answer (score 2):

You can use the quotient rule directly: $$\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{(2x+5)^3-6x(2x+5)^2}{(2x+5)^6} = \frac{2x+5-6x}{(2x+5)^4} = \frac{-4x+5}{(2x+5)^4}.$$
This in fact indicates that you've got a little mistake: it's $(2x+5)^{-4}$ instead of $(2x+5)^2$ in what you have written there. I, particularly, prefer to leave stuff in a single fraction.

---

Another approach: writing $y = x(2x+5)^{-3}$ and using the product rule, we have: $$\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = (2x+5)^{-3} - x(-3(2x+5)^{-4}2) = (2x+5)^{-3}-6x(2x+5)^{-4}.$$

Your mistake probably was thinking that $(({\rm stuff})^{-3})'  = -3({\rm stuff})^{-2}$, because $2 < 3$, and also a sign mistake. You *decrease* the exponent, so $-3 \to -4$.

Comment: Can you show me what I did wrong by transferring the denominator into the numerator and then utilizing the product rule?

Comment: @Cetshwayo, I elaborated my answer a bit, check it.

Comment: Your explanation was incorrect. I needed only to transfer the (2x?5)^4 to the denominator and then proceed to create common denominators. Thanks anyway.